# How do you remove a stuck glass door knob?

Tags: antique

I have an antique glass door knob I am trying to remove.
I have removed the screw at the base of the door knob and have tried to unscrew the door knob.  It is stuck.  I have tried spraying WD40 to loosen it up, but that didn't work.  Don't care if I have to break the door knob.  It is being replaced.
Any help would be great.
Thank you./

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a threaded connection. The threaded rod (spindle) looks something like this:

[image]

Now that the set screw is out, lean on it (especially if you don’t care if it breaks).

[Image source](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-Chrome-Glass-Door-Knob-with-Spindle-E-2328/100310175?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD25H%7C25-10_DOOR_LOCKS%7CNA%7CPLA%7C71700000035978698%7C58700004046980562%7C92700033074575176&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvqbaBRCOARIsAD9s1XA1wPXapGyxU1MxikQQvISFfIwj_J5Cyvf5v-7fhQtYe94omnnpwUEaAu8IEALw_wcB&dclid=CPjB8Yygn9wCFchuwQodRIUHbw)

Comment: Seems a shame to break an antique glass door knob. Some antique dealer might be able to sell it to someone who wants it.

Comment: @JimStewart That reminds me, either knob can be removed. OP may want to try the other knob too.